# If else statement error , Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im javascript beginner and tried to perform some if else statements. Basically you can see my own code in line two! until line seven. But dreamwaever marks it always red! So what did i wrong

```
    this.toDataURL = function() {
    if this.path == []
    {
     document.getElementById("canvascontent").value = "Oh yeah";
    }
    else
    {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;
    ctx.drawImage(layer0, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(layer1, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(layer2, 0, 0);
    var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    document.getElementById("canvascontent").value = url;
    }       
};
```

Comment: `if` statements in Javascript require parentheses around the conditional statement. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#If_..._else

Comment: seems you were in hurry

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't feel this should be downvoted...  He even disclaims that he is a beginner.  He has enough of an understanding to ask the question.  Let's not keep beginners from asking questions.

Comment: I've half a mind to downvote all the answers just for jumping for the easy rep and missing the glaring mistake in the logic (`this.path == []` will *always* be false).

Comment: @user1477388: We didn't keep him from asking a question.  We didn't even prevent him from getting an answer.  For the record, I didn't downvote.

Comment: While 4 people were quick to point out the syntax error of missing parenthesis, there is a bigger problem here that needs to be pointed out.  Comparing arrays in javascript via `==` is going to return false all the time.

Comment: @Juhana totally agreed

Comment: Yes sorry, i was confused, because i interchanged it with ruby syntax sorry! But thanks for @tymeJV answer

Comment: @WarrenKrewenki "Comparing arrays in javascript via `==` is going to return false all the time." - how is that true? You can easily compare array references and the result be true. I can't see a use case for it, but maybe you meant comparing an array to `[]` will always be false, which is true. Unless you were trying to compare to the use of `===` which has no difference here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot `()` around your `if` statement:

```
if (this.path == []) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to surrond your `if` statement with parenthesis:

```
if (this.path == []) {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (this.path == []) //You missed to enclose if statement.
```

Usually

```
if ( statement ) {
}
else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot () parenthesis

```
if (this.path == []) {
```

Comment: Those are parentheses, not brackets. These `{}` are brackets.

Comment: No, those are braces.  These `[]` are brackets.